# How to find which OpenGL extensions are supported by a graphic card that I want to buy

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, opengl

I am developing a 3D program using OpenGL/[VTK](http://vtk.org) library on Windows.

I was surprised to found that many seemingly decent graphic cards don't support all OpenGL extensions. 
Example: [NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-525M.43889.0.html) that doesn't support gpu_shader4 extension.

My client wants to buy a dozen of computers, I need to tell them what to buy and  I cannot find this information on the Net. I have checked a lot of sites, they usually mention an OpenGL version supported, but from my experience that never means fully supported.

I know about [OpenGL Extensions Viewer Tool](http://realtech-vr.com/admin/glview), but I cannot run it on computers in a shop, they won't allow. So, is there any way to make sure a graphic card support specific extensions before buying?

Comment: Nvidia provides specifications on every GPU within those specifications Nvidia lists which version of DX and OpenGL/Vulcan is supported.  A 6 generation old GPU isn't "decent" nor is the bottom of the barrel

Comment: I have seen these specifications, they state, for example,  that GeForce GT 525M supports OpenGL 4.0, however I have Toshiba Satellite laptop with this card and it doesn't, that's exactly my problem.

Comment: If the 525M supports OpenGL 4.5 then your card in your laptop supports it also.  If it doesn't that means you don't have the required Nvidia drivers installed.  If your getting an OpenGL error it likely means you don't have the drivers for your iGPU installed.  Be sure your program is trying to use your dGPu not your iGPU

Comment: I checked and rechecked and am absolutely sure I have the latest NVidia drivers installed. About iGPU vs dGPU, it is interesting. How can I make sure? Or should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Programming questions are not on topic how to get an OpenGL to use the correct GPU is out of scope

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to find out what extensions are supported by a graphics card, the [OpenGL Hardware Database](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/) contains thousands of entries with different hardware and software configurations. Click the name of the renderer you wish to view the extensions for and then select the extensions tab. The webpage will then bring up a searchable list of all the supported extensions on that setup.

This is effectively the same as running GLView on the setup they list. For instance, the GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2 running on Windows 10 in OpenGL 4.6.0 from NVIDIA Driver 419.62 supports the GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 extension you need.